# ASP.NET Core - Data protection

Tags: asp.net-core, cryptography, aes, encryption-symmetric, data-protection

In my application I have configured Data Protection mechanism to store generated keys in the file on my system:

```cs
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\keys"));
```

And it is working. In my "keys" directory a file was generated with a content like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<key id="7139a96c-1d75-468f-a343-1d0d363650a7" version="1">
  <creationDate>2019-04-22T14:27:34.9530001Z</creationDate>
  <activationDate>2019-04-22T14:27:34.9359888Z</activationDate>
  <expirationDate>2019-07-21T14:27:34.9359888Z</expirationDate>
  <descriptor deserializerType="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel.AuthenticatedEncryptorDescriptorDeserializer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60">
    <descriptor>
      <encryption algorithm="AES_256_CBC" />
      <validation algorithm="HMACSHA256" />
      <masterKey p4:requiresEncryption="true" xmlns:p4="http://schemas.asp.net/2015/03/dataProtection">
        <!-- Warning: the key below is in an unencrypted form. -->
        <value>JzykGRqFcYWq3MPQAyuXe4IlEGrj62ghnCEMMuv0YzRKmHjzlfSOcbnk7+cJpDGe0PLKfCwcNPfOKplqu1xfDg==</value>
      </masterKey>
    </descriptor>
  </descriptor>
</key>
```

Now I don't understand one thing. I am using AES_256_CBC algorithm, but the length of the key is 88 characters instead of 32 characters.

So I figured out that key is encoded using base64. After decoding we have the following key:

"'<¤qªÜÃÐ+{%jãëh!!2ëôc4Jxóôq¹äïç    ¤1ÐòÊ|,4÷Î*j»_"

But it has 66 characters instead of 32. How to get the 32 bits AES symmetric key, because I don't understand how ASP.NET Core is saving this key.

I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: YES! I'm trying to persist the key through Redis but I can't find any documentation on the de/serialization structure. Convert.FromBase64String(key) yields a 64 byte value, but AES_256_CBC only works with a 32 byte key?

Answer (score 1):

The 'masterKey' value in the keyring seems to actually be a 64 byte Key Derivation Key (KDK), not a simple base64 AES key.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/subkeyderivation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

This means that you can derive the AES subkey from this KDK. This is how the default [ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptor.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/Managed/ManagedAuthenticatedEncryptor.cs) implementation does it.

If I can find or write a standalone key extractor function I'll add it here (unless someone beats me to it).

Hope that helps!

Edit 1:

Five days of work later and I have been able to hack together various parts of the [AspNetCore codebase](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src) into [this monstrosity](https://gist.github.com/badcommandorfilename/a6dee79ff2d46be29aeb5a9890cb8d90). If you can get the AAD value right, this will extract the AES and SHA256 keys from the KDK and then decrypt an ASPNetCore shared cookie payload.

Answer (score 1):

To help you out I wrote an implementation that stores the Data Proteciton key ring in Azure Key Vault. I blogged about that here:

[Storing the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault](https://www.edument.se/en/blog/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault)

However, the question is why you need to deal with the individual keys on a byte/base64 level? To store them elsewhere you simply implement the IXmlRepository interface and using it is very simple. No need to deal with the raw key bytes.